# R - generic function to plot dataframe with ggplot2 (multiple columns)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and want to plot it with ggplot2. The first column is datetime in the Posixct format, and the next columns are all numeric.

```
                datetime instr1 instr2 instr3 instr4 
12895 2018-05-08 05:11:00     NA  41.8  36.9   6.5
12896 2018-05-08 05:12:00     NA  42.1  34.2   8.3
12897 2018-05-08 05:13:00     NA  44.2  28.7   8.1
12898 2018-05-08 05:14:00     NA  54.7  29.1   7.6
12899 2018-05-08 05:15:00     NA  55.8  30.3   7.5
12900 2018-05-08 05:16:00     NA  60.5  33.7   5.8
```

I wrote a generic function with a for-loop

```
plot_df_with_datetime <- function(df, interval){

  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = datetime))

  for (i in 2:length(colnames(df))){

    p <- p +  geom_line(aes(y = get("df")[,colnames(df)[i]],  color = colors()[i])) 
  }

  p

}
```

However, it seems that the for loop doesn't add another line to the plot, but overwrites the last line.
I'd be quite grateful if someone can point out the mistake. If I do it "by hand", this code works with my dataset:

```
ggplot(NO2, aes(x = datetime)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = instr1 , color = "instr1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = instr2 , color = "instr2"))
```

Comment: Use `aes_string` not `aes(y = get("df")[,colnames(df)[i]] ...`

Comment: @smci, not really. You may pass variables in a loop but could not pass additional geom_line since geom_line() is not string, it's a function.

Comment: @Aleksandr: I'm saying pass string variables using `aes_string` not `aes`